separate object by vertex groups beginning with the last vertex group
I have a script which separates the object by vertex groups. But it separates the vertex groups beginning with the first vertex group. I want it to seperate it by vertex groups beginning with the last vertex group. What do I need to change?



scene = bpy.context.scene

for ob in scene.objects:
    
    def main():
        origin_name = bpy.context.active_object.name
        keys = bpy.context.object.vertex_groups.keys()
        real_keys = []
        for gr in keys:
            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="EDIT")
            # Set the vertex group as active
            bpy.ops.object.vertex_group_set_active(group=gr)

            # Deselect all verts and select only current VG
            bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')
            bpy.ops.object.vertex_group_select()
            # bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='INVERT')
            try:
                bpy.ops.mesh.separate(type="SELECTED")
                real_keys.append(gr)
            except:
                pass
        for i in range(1, len(real_keys) + 1):
            bpy.data.objects['{}.{:03d}'.format(origin_name, i)].name = '{}.{}'.format(
                origin_name, real_keys[i - 1])


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
        
#Switch back to object mode
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```


If my answer solved your question, please mark it as a correct answer by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.

Replace
for gr in keys:
with
for gr in reversed(keys):
